# Get tab's memory footprint from Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In Chrome, shift-escape gives you Chrome's task manager.

In the task manager, you can see various stats, including the "memory footprint" of a tab.

I'd like to get that value in Selenium.  Is there a way to do so?

Apparently there is a [chrome.processes API](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/processes) which looks like it could be useful, if it could be accessed from Selenium.

Comment: Selenium alone can't help, whats your binding language though ?

Comment: Java is what I've been using

Answer (score 0):

You can [execute arbitrary JavaScript code](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) from Selenium therefore you can access i.e. [Window.Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) object in general and [Windows.Performance.Memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/memory) object in particular

Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://accounts.seetest.io/signup')
print(driver.execute_script("return window.performance.memory"))
driver.quit()
```

Example output:

```
{'jsHeapSizeLimit': 2197815296, 'totalJSHeapSize': 23449360, 'usedJSHeapSize': 14905688}
```

Comment: yes, that gives me js heap info, but i specifically want the "memory footprint" of the browser tab, as presented in Chrome's task manager.  thanks.